# Why do I have frame dropped but no main script is used

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, render, requestanimationframe

I am currently trying to improve animations performances on my project. I have so issues with one animation that I don't understand. The slowdowns occurs on devices not that old (Honor 9, Pixel 5). I am usually arround 20 fps, I would love to be above 30, or event at 60 (I am on a pixel 6a).

For context :

- I use a requestAnimationFrame loop to play my animation.
- I only modify opacity and transform on my elements.

I get a lot of frame drop but the main thread does not seems to be used at this point.

I'm adding the performances report to my message.
[image: Performance report]

As you can see, I have a lot of frame dropped from 2100ms to 2300ms, but not a lot is going on in the main thread, and I can't figure why my frames are dropped. I know I have a long task (100ms) before and a long one (210ms) after, but can this be the cause of the drop ? I've try reducing it, but I feel like this does not impact my animation that much.

For my animations, I used the following code :

AnimatedValue.ts

```js
export class AnimatedValue {
    startTime = 0;
    steps = 0;

    constructor(private readonly progressCallback: (progress: number) => void, private readonly duration = 1000) {}

    animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame((chrono) => {
            if (!this.startTime) {
                this.startTime = chrono;
                this.steps = 0;
            }
            const elapsedTime = chrono - this.startTime;
            const progress = elapsedTime / this.duration;
            if (progress < 1) {
                this.progressCallback(progress);
                this.animate();
                this.steps++;
            } else {
                this.progressCallback(1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Animate.ts

```js
const animate = async (callback: (progress: number) => void, duration: number, onEnd = () => {}) => {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
        const animation = new AnimatedValue((progress) => {
            callback(progress);
            if (progress === 1) {
                requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                    onEnd();
                    resolve();
                });
            }
        }, duration);
        animation.animate();
    });
};


export const animateOpen = async (
    feedPlayerElement: HTMLElement,
    backgroundElement: HTMLElement | null,
    fromInformation: { originX?: number; originY?: number },
) => {
    const { originX = 50, originY = 50 } = fromInformation;
    feedPlayerElement.style.transformOrigin = `${originX}% ${originY}%`;

    await animate(
        (progress) => {
            feedPlayerElement.style.transform = `scale(${progress})`;
            if (backgroundElement) backgroundElement.style.opacity = progress.toString();
        },
        CLOSE_ANIMATION_DURATION,
        () => {
            feedPlayerElement.style.transform = '';
            feedPlayerElement.style.transformOrigin = '';
            if (backgroundElement) backgroundElement.style.opacity = '';
        },
    );
};
```

I am usually arround 20 fps, I would love to be above 30, or event at 60 (I am on a pixel 6a).